# How-to use SignalR with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, signalr

I have a Xamarin project on my Mac, where I’m trying to get SiganlR to work.

I'm having trouble getting the dll's imported.

I have tried to import the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.dll to my Referencer folder in my solution. When I’m adding the dll I get the following message:

> Could not get full name for assembly
>   'mypath/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.dll'

And then when I’m trying to build I get another error:

> Metadata file `mypath/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.dll' does not contain valid metadata.

I'm new in the Xamarin environment, so some help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get SignalR working in a Xamarin iOS project via the [SignalR Client Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client). I did it via VS.Net rather than Xamarin Studio, however you should be able to use the same package in Xamarin Studio.

If you're using Xamarin Studio on the Mac then you'll have to install the NuGet package manager first, of which there is a pretty good blog post of how to do that [here](http://barambani.wordpress.com/2013/10/07/add-nuget-package-manager-and-servicestack-to-xamarin-studio-projects-2/).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use/add the `Xamarin` package at the [GitHub page](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/xamarin)

Comment: How do I add the package? I have added the folder SignalRPackage to my solution, but how do I use it?